# Does Ganon get super armor during his Warlock Punch?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Sometimes, while I am Ganon, my Warlock Punch (Basic B attack) is unstoppable, to even a great barrage, but sometimes a single attack cancels my move. What happens during Ganon's Warlock Punch to Ganon?

Comment: You can get super armor for sure if you rotate while doing it. It only lasts for a few frames though, much like the home run bat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes indeed, there is a sizeable period of time during the Warlock Punch in which you will not flinch from anything (though you can still be grabbed). However, it only occurs when you use the attack on the ground, not in the air.

- Warlock Punch (default): super armour from 11-63, hits on 70-71
- Warlock Blade (custom 1): super armour from 8-53, wind on 53-59, hits on 60-66
- Warlock Thrust (custom 2): no super armour, hits on 40-41

Note: Custom special timing might be off a bit because I'm not yet 100% sure how the animation speed multipliers work.

Answer (score 1):

Like the bat, there's a few super armour frames towards the end of the move just before the hit. If they hit you at the start of it you'll be interrupted but if they hit during the super armour frames they're likely to get a face full of fist. A more extreme example is Ike's B, when fully charged or extremely close to it, it has super armour as you release it but only at that point.